# Why am I getting an 'internal server error' with heroku deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, ejs

I just deployed a small weather app project with Heroku and I am getting an internal server error when user enters an invalid city or zip code.  I added a .catch in my route to render an error page if this happens, and it works exactly as intended in my local version, but not on the deployed version.  Does anyone know why this might be?  I am using .ejs templates to render my pages.

```
app.get("/results_city", (req, res) => {
  let query = req.query.search;
  console.log("Search params:", query);
  let weatherApiKey = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;
  let weatherUrl =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
    query +
    "&appid=" +
    weatherApiKey;
  rp(weatherUrl)
    .then((body) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(body);
      res.render("results", { data: data });
      console.log(data);
      })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err) {
        res.render("Error")
        return;
      }
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share your heroku logs for this error